# Syntax error in CSET library

Tags: javascript, syntax, safari, google-chrome

I am using [CSET](http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_cset), a library for Unicode character classes for Javascript.  It loads fine in Firefox, IE8, and Opera, but fails in Google Chrome and Safari 4 with a syntax error.  Strangely enough, the syntax errors are different.

From [`cset_production.js`](http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/cset_production.js):

### Safari

```
SyntaxError: Parse error
(line 255)

CSET=function(){
// ...
var g=this
return {import:function(prefix,object){object=object||g
 var i,l,e,es=           // SyntaxError: Parse error (line 255)
 [['fromChar',fC]
 ,['fromInt',fI]
 ,['universe',U]
 ,['nil',nil]
 ,['empty',empty]
 ,['singleton',one]
 ,['fromIntRange',fIR]
 ,['fromCharRange',fCR]
 ,['fromUnicodeGeneralCategory',fGC]
 ,['complement',comp]
 ,['fromList',fL]
 ,['fromString',fS]
 ,['member',member]
 ,['difference',diff]
 ,['union',union]
 ,['intersection',inter]
 ,['toRegex',reCC]
 ,['show',show]
 ]
 for(i=0,l=es.length;i<l,e=es[i];i++)
  object[(prefix||'')+e[0]]=e[1]}}
}();
```

What is the cause of Safari's syntax error and what can I do to correct the problem?

### Google Chrome

```
uncaught exception SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

[hi,lo]=surrogatePair(c)     // Line 200
```

Is this error called on legal code?  Or is Google Chrome's parser correct in erroring on this line?

Comment: When I ran that in google chrome, it returned an Object and didn't error out at all.

Comment: @Salty, What "that" did you run?

Comment: cset_production.js, and cset_source.js (from the same site). I opened the javascript console and ran both and didn't find any errors. My chrome installation is a beta, however...maybe that could be affecting it?

Comment: @Salty, Errors in the latest Beta (http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) on Windows 7 here: http://jsbin.com/oqeyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari had issues with the use if `import` as an object property.  Also, it got confused by a unicode character in the source code.  Correcting these two problems lead to the problems Chrome was having.

Chrome's problem (and thus Safari's problem later) was easily fixed.

<strike>I have contacted the author of CSET and hopefully these issues will be fixed in another release.</strike>

A new version of CSET has been released which corrects these issues.